# Animation nodes setup not rendering as it appears int the viewport

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I've been researching for a project and have developed a few techniques that I'd like to use. However one of them (a simplified version of which I've put into a linked zip) isn't rendering in cycles the same as it appears in the viewport or even in openGL render...

I can use the openGL as I'll do FX in post anyway but it'd be good to solve this issue as I would like to develop it further and without it rendering properly I'll be stuck when the client asks me why I can't :)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sv29eylova17jg/soundscape.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you used a relatively bad practice for projects that need to be rendered in the end. Namely you created a feedback loop, meaning you use the **same mesh as input and output**.

You should try to build a node setup that calculates the whole result in each frame deterministically. The result in one frame should not depend on the results in previous frames.

This is problematic because, when rendering, the AN node tree might be executed more than once per frame.

Another thing you can try is to bake your mesh animation into an alembic file.

Comment: Thanks Jacques, at least I know that I am doing something wrong :)

Comment: I'll have a further research and see if I can find a way to solve this, cheers!

Comment: Ah cool, alembic does work, so even if I can't reason my way out of this I can do that, cheers, loving this addon and really happy I'm finally on a project where I think I can actually use it :) (heavy rock video - I'll definitely share it when it's good to go)

Comment: I've been trying to adapt what I'm trying to do by using lists of the points but keep running into the same issue; that I'd need to somehow store the previous frame's points in a structure and the only way I can see to do it is in a mesh... is there any material or source that could guide me to a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, I made it work

I used a particle system - with a single point source (Thanks to Jimmy Gunawan, spotted that tip in one of your tutorials as a way to get particle systems to only output a single particle from exactly where you want it each frame)

Then using a loop, I combine the particle systems into one and then use that to generate a mesh as before, I'll link a file here :)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dlers9behbmoe5/soundscape002.zip?dl=0

Comment: Actually, it seems to crash quite a lot on render :(