# Animation nodes setup not updating when rendering

Tags: python, rendering, transforms, animation-nodes

I have a setup with animation nodes. I think I misused it a little bit, since I am not using it for a continuous animation, but rather to generate a different random frame every frame. However, it is completely deterministic, since every random aspect is seeded by the current frame.

Now my problem is: In the end, I want to move around a few objects with a matrix or a transform (don't care which). It works fine in the viewport, but when rendering everything works except moving the objects (I'm also instancing some objects, assigning a material, calling scripts etc., which all seems to work).

Now I read [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92408/animation-nodes-setup-not-rendering-as-it-appears-int-the-viewport), but that does not seem to be my issue since no information is preserved across frames and everything is deterministic via the seed.
I found a little workaround to make it work, but it seems more like a hack:
If I render my animation with the following script, it works:

```
def fake_render():
    scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]

    for i in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1):
        scene.frame_current = i
        bpy.ops.render.render()
```

It also works if I change the frame, then turn off automatic execution of the node tree and then render the frame like normally. However, I now can't render it as an animation.
Any idea what could cause this behavior? How can I make it render as animation?

Edit: Some additional information:
It seems to render before everything is executed.
During rendering, in the viewport I can see that all the objects get instantiated at (0,0,0) as I want them to. Then, it renders, and then the objects move towards to where I want them to be.

This is the part that is not executed, everything before seems to work:
[image: This is not being executed, everything before seems to be executed.]

Here you can find the [.blend file](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/069eac85).
Here you can find the [re-upload of the file](https://ufile.io/nj7q8)

Comment: Can you provide the blend file?

Comment: @OmarAhmad I edited the question to include it.

Comment: I think you are using an old version, the node tree doesn't work for me. So I may not be able to help you. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0, is there a specific error?

Comment: All connections are gone for me.

Comment: Ok that is weird, I'll re-upload it, but if that does not work I do not know what to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67955/discussion-between-omar-ahmad-and-runorveith).